# How to re-direct Curl progress meter to a file?

Tags: curl

I was trying to upload a file via curl tftp as part of a shell script and trying to determine whether the tftp is succeeded based on the progress meter. Any suggestions ?

```
curl --upload-file <filename> tftp://<tftp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the output of a command using

```
curl --upload-file tftp:// 2> file
```

The `2>` redirects the stderr output to a file.

If you are using a (bash) shell script, you should use the exit value. curl should have an exit value of 0 if it succeeded. For example:

```
#/bin/bash

# Upload file
curl --upload-file tftp://....;

# Store the exit value, since it will be lost after the next command
exitvalue=$?;

# Check if the exit value equals 0
if [[ $exitvalue -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Download succeeded!";
else
    echo "Download failed, exit value $exitvalue";
fi
```

Comment: thanks! it helped..... but in cases when the tftp times out for some reason, does curl returns any value to help terminating the shell script ?

Comment: The curl man page (`man curl`) says the following:
`28     Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.`
This means you can check if the exit value equals 28 in order to detect a timeout.

Comment: Ok.. This will probably end in holding the shell and won't return to the prompt until the operation timeout is reached. Is there way I can terminate the shell script with pre-defined timeout value which i can against the curl tftp operation ?

Comment: The curl documentation also says the following: ` --connect-timeout SECONDS  Maximum time allowed for connection`. This means your command should contain `--connect-timeout 3` for a 3 second time-out. Try reading the man page (`man curl`), it contains very useful explanation.